# Visual Studio Online cannot build project due to Entity Framework reference cannot be resolved

Tags: entity-framework, msbuild, nuget, tfsbuild, azure-devops

What can I do to fix this build? Entity Framework was added to this project via NuGet.

All projects compile without issues on local system. But the build fails on Visual Studio Online.

By turning on Diagnostic logging, I am able to trace to this warning which makes my builds failed:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework.SqlServer". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

Comment: Mark EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll as copy always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this error simply by right clicking at the solution in Solution Explorer and select Enable NuGet Package Restore.

That adds a few more files to my solution and modify a few project files. The build server can then restore the packages at build time and is happy in the end.

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT** right-click the project and chose "Enable NuGet Package Restore". This is the "old way" of doing package restores as per the [Nuget Docs](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore).

Package restoration should happen as part of the build process by default. If it's not (which seems to be the case), you've got a different problem, but there's not enough information to say what.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. However, Visual Studio 2013 has already taken care of creating the .nuget folder as suggested by the link in your post. This means it's no longer a deprecated way. Besides, it did resolve my errors on VisualStudio.com build server.